# python: найти второе совпадение подстроки в строке и вывести 2 символа до этого совпадения!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Kак заставить программу выдать при поиске второго совпадения строки string_2 в string_1 два символа до этого совпадения - программа должна выдать ответ - 1G

```
string_1 = 'uvasdvbaodaiudhfuiahsdfiuabsdgihuaishguapishgdaipsgfuda1Guvasd'
string_2 = 'uvasd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string_1 = 'uvasdvbaodaiudhfuiahsdfiuabsdgihuaishguapishgdaipsgfuda1Guvasd'
string_2 = 'uvasd'
secondPos = string_1.index(string_2, string_1.index(string_2) + len(string_2), len(string_1))
print(string_1[secondPos - 2:secondPos])
```

Данной строкой мы находим первое вхождение после первого вхождения в строке:

```
secondPos = string_1.index(string_2, string_1.index(string_2) + len(string_2), len(string_1))
```

Данной строкой мы выводим 2 символа до второго вхождения:

```
print(string_1[secondPos - 2:secondPos])
```

Answer (score 2):

Совсем коротенькое решение, как вариант:

```
string_1 = 'uvasdvbaodaiudhfuiahsdfiuabsdgihuaishguapishgdaipsgfuda1Guvasd'
string_2 = 'uvasd'
print(string_1.split(string_2)[1][-2:])
```

- `string_1.split(string_2)` разбиваем первую строку вхождениями второй строки
- `[1]` берём 2-й кусочек получившегося разбиения, поскольку индексирование в Питоне идёт с нуля, используем индекс 1
- `[-2:]` берём последние два символа строки

Вывод:

```
1G
```